# CSS: Is it possible to create two columns left floated but in order?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok I know the title doesn't make much sense, but bear with me.  I just don't know how to explain what I am accomplishing in words...   I mocked up a layout in photoshop which I've attached below to best explain what I am trying to accomplish.

Basicly I have a blog which spits out my stories in order from story #1 - 5.  I can assign a unique div class/id to the blog story depending on how I want that story to display.   In my example **.small** and **.large**

Now, heres the hardpart.  Wordpress will put out the stories in order from #1-5 BUT I want to display all the .small stories in a left floated column and all the .large stories in another column.

My first instinct was to try to programatically have wordpress change the order in which it was pushing out stories to make it fit my columns, but that became to server intensive, then I thought of doing a very complex re-arrangement using jQuery to reorder everything in the user browser.  The second way is progressing, but it still has quite a few bugs, so it dawned on me that this might be possible with the power of CSS.  I've been messing with it all day, but can't get it to work with CSS.

Was hoping someone else had any idea of how to pull something this crazy off?

To cut to the chase, just scroll to my attached picture below :)[image]

Comment: Just give them a width that fits both divs into one row (or use a percentage for width value).

Comment: Yes, thats basically how a responsive grid works.

Comment: @designcise I'm probably reading you incorrectly, but I tried to assign a float:left to .small and .large and change .small to 33% width and .large to 66%.  It works great for Div 1 and 2 but then div 3 and 4 stack horizontally to each other.  But i'm clearly looking at this the wrong way...

Comment: Guys I wouldn't be so sure that's easily done. 4 & 5 are in a different order when there are two columns ...

Comment: What does your first picture when the divs are 100% shows? How it was? And now you simply want 2-column grid for any screen size? Is this what you want? http://www.bootply.com/t0ce5qyU8f

Comment: Do you have any margin/padding/border applied to your element? You need to show us the code so we can help/assess your issues better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a CSS solution that works if: 1) the squares are within a container that allows only two to be displayed in one line and 2) the number of `.large` blocks can exceed the number of `.small` blocks by only 1.  Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uPzh6/2/.

Keep in mind that it is possible to create greater separation between two blocks in one line through the use of margins.  See a different fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/VEEE6/1/.

The solution works with an arbitrary order of `.large` and `.small`.

HTML:

```
<div id = "wrapper">
    <div class="small">1</div>
    <div class="large">2</div>
    <div class="large">3</div>
    <div class="small">4</div>
    <div class="small">5</div>
    <div class="small">6</div>
    <div class="large">7</div>
    <div class="small">8</div>
    <div class="large">9</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 210px;
    text-align: right;
}

#wrapper > div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 1);
    border: 1px solid rgba(30, 30, 30, 1);
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#wrapper > div.small {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    line-height: 100px;
    color: yellow;
}

#wrapper > div.small:before {
    content: "small: ";
}

#wrapper > div.large {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 100px;
}

#wrapper > div.large:before {
    content: "LARGE: ";
}
```

Comment: This is working really well in the Fiddle!!  I cant get it to work at all in my implementation, working on it now to see what the disconnect might be

Answer (score 1):

Going by your images, it looks like you want this:

http://jsfiddle.net/JYdB9/4/

```
@media (min-width: 1px) {
    .wrapper {
        text-align: right;
    }
    .small {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .large {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 50%;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .small + .small {
        clear: left;
    }
}
```

There are a couple of provisos:

1. You need a wrapper to align the `inline-block` elements to the right;
2. You cannot have any whitespace between the `<div>`s (gets rid of the pesky whitespace issue)

Comment: divs 2 and 5 are not at the very top.

Comment: This is some pretty incredible thinking!  Its very close to working.  My image above is just a random example, and in fact on a real blog the order will always be different.  So when testing out your fiddle, I did come across some situations where it doesnt quite work  http://jsfiddle.net/JYdB9/    I think it has to do with the nth-child being 2n.  Thats all new CSS to me, so i'm looking it up now to see a way around this..

Comment: Hi @Mark hmm if you change it to http://jsfiddle.net/JYdB9/1/ it will clear properly, however the gaps DRD mentioned are still present ... still thinking about that.

Comment: @setek .. Amazing.. its so close now  the gap is very pronouced now on my design since the divs are quite block/large, but this is so close, im sure theres a way to fix this

Comment: Also, keep in mind that the solution has to be generalizable, because the order of `.small` and `.large` can vary.

Comment: This requires a wrapper element to have `text-align: right;` on it (for the `inline-block` elements,) and it requires no whitespace in between the `<div>` elements (to remove the pesky space when using `inline-block`) but otherwise works: http://jsfiddle.net/JYdB9/3/ what do you think?

Comment: @climbinghobo yes, if you read the comments we've been discussing limitations and other avenues

Comment: @DRD your solution has a pretty huge limitation in that _"the number of .large blocks can exceed the number of .small blocks by only 1"_ sorry, but I don't like that idea. My edited solution has less limitation than yours.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making two containing div's (columns), one for .small and one for .large, and then with jquery .appendTo() move  .large to right column and .small to left. Of course this is not a css solution, but something simple like floating .small to left and .large to right will not work in this case.

this kind of solution **will not work**:

```
<body style="width: 300px">
    <div style="float: left; clear: left; width: 100px; height: 100px; background: #ccc;">left</div>
    <div style="float: right; clear: right; width: 200px; height: 200px; background: #ccc;">right</div>
    <div style="float: left; clear: left; width: 100px; height: 100px; background: #ccc;">left</div>
    <div style="float: right; clear: right; width: 200px; height: 200px; background: #ccc;">right</div>
    <div style="float: right; clear: right; width: 200px; height: 200px; background: #ccc;">right</div>
    <div style="float: right; clear: right; width: 200px; height: 200px; background: #ccc;">right</div>
    <div style="float: right; clear: right; width: 200px; height: 200px; background: #ccc;">right</div>
    <div style="float: left; clear: left; width: 100px; height: 100px; background: #ccc;">left</div>
   <div style="float: left; clear: left; width: 100px; height: 100px; background: #ccc;">left</div>
```

basically you need two columns.

Comment: Thanks Treavis, my gut tells me I will have to do this with jQuery like your suggestion.. my own homegrown solution is riddled with bugs still, so I was hoping for a more elegant CSS solution.  I hope we're both wrong and this wont require some ugly JS hacking to physically move the divs around :)